# Using a different font with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a different font for my website, which is not a regular webfont. I have created EOT files already. Now how can I integrate those fonts with twitter bootstrap ? Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend trying to use google again. Or the search at the top of this page. You'll find tons of results of this same subject. Hint: "custom font on website".

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use custom font's in website. But that was not the question. I asked how to integrate with twitter bootstrap.

Comment: If you already know how to use them I don't understand what the problem is. You use them with twitter bootstrap just like you'd use them in any other website.

Comment: @dxenaretionx You should take the time to accept some answers if you think they're valid.

Comment: @mMoovs he's trying to find out what classes etc he needs to override. That's why I'm here too.

Answer (score 50):

The easiest way I've seen is to use [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts).

Go to Google Fonts and choose a font, then  Google will give you a link to put in your HTML.

[image: Google's link to your font]

Then add this to your custom.css:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Your Font' !important;
}
p, div {
    font-family: 'Your Font' !important;
}
```

or

```
body {
   font-family: 'Your Font' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can find a customizer on the official website, which allows you to set some LESS variables, as `@font-family-base`. Link your custom fonts in your layout, and use your custom generated bootstrap style.

[Link here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables)

For an example with the `@font-face` rule, using WOFF format (which is pretty good for browser compatibility), add this CSS in your `app.css` file **and** include your custom `boostrap.css` file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  font-style:  normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(link-to-proxima-nova-font.woff) format('woff');
}
```

[Please note Proxima Nova is under a license.](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/proxima-nova)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I saw that I can add different font name in customize page. But how the files will be included ? Or it will get automatically from name ? I,m trying to use 'Proxima Nova' fonts. Can you be little more specific ?

Comment: You'll need to include your font files manually. This generator just  insure you to not have overriden CSS rules.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can create a customized build on bootstrap, just change the font name in the following pages

Bootstrap 2.3.2
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables

Bootstrap 3
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables

After that, make sure to use proper @font-face in a css file and link that to your page. Or you could use font kit generators.

Answer (score 2):

you can customize twitter bootstrap css file, open the `bootstrap.css` file on a text editor, and change the font-family with your font name and SAVE it.

OR got to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and make a customized twitter bootstrap

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I saw that I can add different font name in customize page. But how the files will be included ? Or it will get automatically from name ? I,m trying to use 'Proxima Nova' fonts. Can you be little more specific ?

Comment: use the font-face source property

Comment: @font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'),
     url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to include your font in your website (or your CSS, to be more specific) using an appropriate `@font-face` rule.
From here on there are multiple ways to proceed. One thing I would *not* do is to edit the bootstrap.css directly - since once you get a newer version your changes will be lost. You do however have the possibility to customize your bootstrap files (there's a customize page on their website). Just enter the name of your font with all the fallback names into the corresponding typography textbox. Of course you will have to do this whenever you get a new or updated version of your bootstrap files.
Another chance you have is to overwrite the bootstrap rules within a different stylesheet. If you do this you just have to use selectors that are as specific as (or more specific than) the bootstrap selectors.
Side note: If you care about browser support a single EOT version of your font might not be sufficient. See http://caniuse.com/eot for a support table.