# Use a single font for full bootstrap website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-family

How can I give all `paragraphs` `heading` of a bootstrap website a `font-family`, `Signika`.

I am giving it like this but doesn't look like working.

```
@font-face {  
  font-family:Signika !important;
  src: url(../assets/Signika.otf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the font for this tags.
Add this to the end of your css.

```
h1 {
    font-family: Signika;
}
h2 {
    font-family: Signika;

}
h3 {
    font-family: Signika;

}
p {
    font-family: Signika;
}
```

see [using a different font with twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740757/using-a-different-font-with-twitter-bootstrap)